# Using segmented control as a quasi-radio button

Tags: iphone, ipad, human-interface

I use this segmented control as a mechanism for the user to select an option rather than control any subviews.

IMHO this looks better and is more usable that a select picker which would be very heavy on the screen for a small selection like the one i need.

Anything wrong / inefficient / immoral / illegitimate about this approach ? Would apple care about this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's stories about apple approving a certain approach in one case and rejecting it in another.

I don't think you're doing something nasty here, however. There are apps out there where the iOS UI scheme has been abused beyond belief and they still made it into the store. Actually I've used a segmented control in a very similar way (for similar reasons) and the app has been approved, so...

Answer (score 0):

this is completely ordinary. Apple wouldn't say anything if everything is working properly. So if your question is: "is this all right?" then the answer is "yes, absolutely"